# TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function bootstrap issues

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the Bootstrap popover, but I keep getting this error in firebug:

```
TypeError: $(...).popover is not a function
```

This is how I load it all:

```
  <a id="example" class="btn btn-success" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" rel="popover" href="#">abc</a>


  <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>

  <script>
     setTimeout(function (){ $("#example").popover("show");},4000);
  </script>';
```

Comment: jQuery has to come before the Bootstrap support script.

Comment: Same issue, even with jquery first

Comment: Are all of the JavaScript files loaded correctly?

Comment: I will try with full path, but all are shown as included in dreamweaver aswell

Comment: Found the issue, sorry for the stupid question, had another version of Jquery sneaking itself in at the end of the page

Comment: Try `var jc = jQuery.noConflict(); jc.("#example").popover("show");` is work fine. Example https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: If you like any of the answers, please ensure you accept one of them, so that others know what to look for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

This is what worked for me, I changed the order of jQuery and bootsrap libraries.  Also, I am using the libraries from a CDN.  That should make no difference.

```
<a id="example" class="btn btn-success" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" rel="popover" 

href="#">abc</a>


  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http:////cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <script>
     setTimeout(function (){ $("#example").popover("show");},4000);
  </script>
```

Comment: If we use separate bootstrap plugin should be in order. Otherwise it get conflicts. Either should use minified or bootstrap all.js

Comment: Important that the script is loaded after the body :)

Answer (score -7):

```
<a id="example" class="btn btn-success" data-original-title="Twitter Bootstrap Popover" data-content="It's so simple to create a tooltop for my website!" rel="popover" href="#">abc</a>
  <script>
     setTimeout(function (){ $("#example").popover("show");},4000);
  </script>
  <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: That just made it a different error! Using $ before jQuery is used.

Comment: you need jquery ready statement
$(function(){ 
//code goes here.. to make sure that html is loaded
}):

Comment: this is a very duck tape approach

Comment: makes another Error.